# Can I compile swift code such that public is internal, and vice versa?

Tags: ios, swift, preprocessor, swift-package-manager

I'm creating a small embeddable swift library. I want this library to be available both as a regular swiftpm package, and a single file that can be copy/pasted into another library as an internal implementation detail.
I want to do this to get around the "transitive dependency" problem -- for example given:

- `MyApp` references `BigLib:v2`
- `BigLib:v2` references `SmallLib:v1`

There is now a transitive dependency from `MyApp` -> `BigLib:v2` -> `SmallLib:v1`

But what if `MyApp` also wants to reference `SmallLib:v2`? We end up in the scenario where both v1 and v2 of `SmallLib` are referenced, and it's my understanding that this can't be done in the Swift/Xcode/SwiftPM world.

My idea was that if my `SmallLib` can be copy/pasted inside the `BigLib` project and made internal, then from the perspective of outside code such as `MyApp` it will cease to exist and there will be no conflicts.

This leads me to the part where in C++ I'd (ab)use the preprocessor and do something like this:

```
#if !defined(SMALLLIB_EMBEDDED)
#define SMALLLIB_PUBLIC public
#else
#define SMALLLIB_PUBLIC internal
#endif

SMALLLIB_PUBLIC protocol SmallProtocol {
   ...
}
```

Under such a scheme BigLib could define the `SMALLLIB_EMBEDDED` compiler flag to make the SmallLib stuff non-public, and all would be well.

Is such a thing achievable in swift?

Alternatively is there some other way to get around the transitive dependency problem?

Comment: What I'll do in the interim is when I do the step of copy/pasting the source code for SmallLib into BigLib is to manually search/replace public with /*public*/ to comment it out. It'd be nice to have something that didn't rely on manual search/replace though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can probably do to get this behavior is to use the hidden `@_spi` feature that is in the 5.3+ compiler. The PR adding it to the language is [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/29810).

What you would have to do is mark every type and function with `@_spi(public)` or whatever identifier you want and then those that copy it in would be able to access them and only those that import your module with `@_spi(public) import SmallLib` and you should be able to access all of those members.

Of course this being a hidden feature that hasn't gone through evolution means it is likely to change at least a bit before it becomes official.